# Android `CountDownTimer` broken?

Tags: android

i used a 60 second timer count down using what looked to be a very promising `CountDownTimer`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

but sometimes i'm finding that the calls there hasn't actually been 60 calls to `onTick` before the `onFinish` executes. often times i find the timer stuck on 1 instead of 0 because of this reason. When i stick in a debugger, this becomes even more apparent. in fact, when i put a breakpoint in the debugger, the `onTick` has been called as few as only 50 times before `onFinish` gets called.

am i missing something, or should i really just assume that there is no guarantee that `onFinish` is called if and only if all of the supposed `onTick` functions have been called?

here's my code:

```
    public SomeRetryTimer(long future, long countDownInterval) {
        super( 60*1000, 1000);
        mCurrentCountdown = 60
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        mCurrentCountdown--;

        doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        finishStuff(); // at this point, i find that mCurrentCountdown is sometimes not 0
    }
```

am i doing something wrong, or is this an issue with the API? i mean, i looked at the source code and the timer SHOULD be synchronized in the handler... are messages getting posted out of order?

Comment: Is checking the value of `mCurrentCountdown` the only way you know this happens? I don't suppose there is anyway that `doSomething()` could be causing an issue? I've never had a problem with this class, myself. So I'm curious if there is an issue with it

Answer (score 0):

the ticks aren't at a guaranteed interval... That's why it passes the `long` to your `onTick`..

from the docs

> The calls to onTick(long) are synchronized to this object so that one
>   call to onTick(long) won't ever occur before the previous callback is
>   complete. This is only relevant when the implementation of
>   onTick(long) takes an amount of time to execute that is significant
>   compared to the countdown interval.

So this implies that if the work you perform in onTick takes longer than the "regular interval" that interval will become more and more irregular. This will certainly be the case when you add the overhead of the debugger.

If you must do work in onTick, I would do it in a thread that is not on the timer's thread. But even then I don't think you can or should rely on getting a certain number of ticks. It seems risky and error prone when realtime semantics are not ensured by the OS.